# The gambler chooses dice at random, and rolls it $six$ times. What is the probability that fair die was chosen?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Assume that a gambler has two dice, one of which is **fair**, and the other is **biased** toward landing on $six$, so that $0.25$ of the time it lands on $six$, and $0.15$ of the time it lands on each of $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ and $5$.

**Question:** The gambler chooses dice at random, and rolls it $six$ times, getting the values, $4$, $3$, $6$, $6$, $5$, $5$. The outcomes of rolls are mutually independent. What is the probability that fair die was chosen?

**MY WORKING**

Let $F$ denote the event that the **fair die** is chosen.

Let $F'$ denote the event that the **biased die** is chosen.

Let $X$ denote the event that die comes up with **4,3,6,6,5,5**

We have to calculate $P(F|X)=?$

By Applying Bayes' Theorem we have:

$P(F|X)=\frac{P(X|F)P(F)}{P(X|F)P(F)+P(X|F')P(F')}$

Here we find that:

$P(F)=\frac{1}{2}$, $P(F')=\frac{1}{2}$

By conditional probability we have:

$P(X|F)=\frac{P(X\cap F)}{P(F)}$

$P(X|F')=\frac{P(X\cap F')}{P(F')}$

Here I am stuck here again. How do I solve the numerator part of above last two equations? Is there a relation between $X$, $F$ AND $X$, $F'$? I know that each roll in the event $X$ is independent, but what about the $X$, $F$ AND $X$, $F'$? I will appreciate any guidance here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$p(A|B) = \frac{p(A,B)}{p(B)}.$$

$A$ is the event that the die was fair.

$B$ is the event that the $6$ die rolls turned out as specified.

$$p(B) = p(A,B) + p(A^C,B).$$

$$p(A|B) = \frac{(1/2) \times (1/6)^6}{[(1/2) \times (1/6)^6] + [(1/2) \times (0.15)^4 \times (0.25)^2]}. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, to compute the probability of event $(A,B)$ occurring, first you have to compute the probability that the fair die was selected.  Then, you have to compute the probability that the exact $6$ rolls occurred, given that the fair die was selected.

In other words, $p(A,B) = p(A) \times p(B|A).$

In (1) above, the analysis, re computing the probability of the event $(A^C,B)$ is virtually identical.

---

**Edit**
For what it's worth, I consider intuition to be a vital part of understanding Probability Theory.  My intuition guided me through the convoluted analysis above.  Intuition is developed by attacking many, many problems in the specific area of Math.

Comment: I have found the answer to be $0.4.$ Is that correct?

Comment: @Ameer786 In the denominator, ignoring the $(1/2)$ factors, I used a calculator to compute the LHS term as  $\approx (2.14334) \times (10)^{-5}$ and similarly calculated the RHS term as $(3.1640625) \times (10)^{-5}.$